# git flyway script merge conflict detection

Tags: git, merge, flyway

For flyway I have directory with lots of SQL scripts.

Each of them starts with version/order number that must be unique.

```
V001__foo.sql
V002__bar.sql
```

Is it possible for git to detect merge conflict, when one branch added `V003_buz.sql` and other trying to add `V003_bug.sql`.

(for this I have a script that is run on jenkins, but thought maybe it would be possible to reveal this already during merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From Git's point of view there is no conflict.**

Git operates at the file level, and during merges detects conflicting changes in the same region of the same file.

But you might be able to achieve what you want with git commit hooks:

- [Git Book - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- [Git Reference - githooks Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)
- [Git Hooks | Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks)
- [Git Hooks: Learn how to use pre-commit hooks, post-commit hooks, post-receive hooks, and more. | Matthew Hudson](https://githooks.com/)

Comment: This is a great idea. I haven't tried this but you might be able to have a git pre-receive hook that did a flyway clean/migrate on a temporary database (as you may not want to clean your dev instance). If this returns an error (which I'm guessing would come with a non zero exit code), either because the SQL is duff, OR because of the flyway versioning "conflict", then you abort the commit.